# Google search returns blank page

Tags: search-engine

When I do a google search for any string it is retuning a blank page. The html source of the returned page looks like this.

```
<html>
<body>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=test+search&meta=&safe=active">
</body>
</html>
```

i.e. there is nothing at all returned to the browser.

But, when I search using google's IP address in the address bar (rather than typing google.com), the search returns required results. (doesn't return blank page anymore).

Why is this strange behavior happening? I am dead certain that it is not blocked at firewall as other users in the network with same access rights as mine are able to work normally with google. And neither is it any setting in the browser.

And it looks to me as if the search request when I search using domain name (google.com) doesn't reach google server at all.

Conceded that it is not a programatical question and though I am able to search using google's IP adress, the issue when using domain name remains an unanswered puzzle to me.

What could be the reason for this rather strange behavior?

Comment: Check your hosts file http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file

Comment: my hosts file has only one entry for localhost nothing else is in there.

Comment: @ChanLFC, check out the updates to my answer - it may be that meta-refresh has been disabled in your browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone's probably hijacked the google.com address on your PC. Try a ping of google.com and see if the address resolves to the same IP as you think it should. Otherwise, they may have hijacked your browser (such as a BHO under IE).

In any case, you're right, this isn't really programming-related.

EDIT: I've just typed that source into a HTML file on the hard drive and changed the 0 to a 5. It successfully refreshes me to Google after 5 seconds which is what I'd expect yours to do.

But, this sort of page-initiated meta-refresh can be disabled in some browsers. For example, if you bring up "Tools" menu, "Internet options", "Security" tab in IE6, you can disable meta-refresh (under "Miscellaneous").

This may be worth looking into, and it depends on the browser you're using. Try typing this exact content into a file x.html and double-clicking on it:

```
<html><body>
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0; URL=http://xxx">
</body></html>
```

It **should** complain about not being able to find xxx. If not, then your browser has somehow disabled meta-refresh (in which case, tell us the browser you're using).

Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) to see how this is meant to work.

Comment: when i ping google.com. this is what i get

Pinging www.l.google.com [209.85.229.147] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Though it is a different IP when visit this IP in browser I reach a google like looking page. And when I do https://209.85.229.147 it changes to google.com in addr.bar

Comment: Certainly seems like a valid page, entering "SO" as a term reroutes me back to www.google.com.au and presents what I'd expect to see (So up near the top).

Comment: Try a different browser, reboot-and-try-again, check with you network people (since you mention firewalls and other users). You need to try these things. Still not related to programming so I don't think you'll get much more help, sorry.

Comment: thanks friend. you've already helped as much as you could.

Comment: i tried with the meta refresh code with allow meta refresh option both enabled and disabled and it complained on both times. don't know how!

Nevertheless, prior to this my allow meta refresh was disabled and search wasnt working. After enabling meta refresh google search started working. thanks.

Comment: just wondering that when i had meta refresh disabled, i was still able to search using IP address. if it really was the problem with meta refresh you think? or something else!

Comment: The IP address you had may have been for the *target* of the refresh, hence no refresh was required. It's only if you go to a site that has the refresh will it not work when refresh is disabled. That's the most likely explanation but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

What is happenning is that `google.com` is soft-redirecting you to `www.google.co.in`, and your browser may have chosen to ignore this redirect.

Can you access `www.google.co.in` (notice the Indian domain) from your broswer?

You may want to check your antivirus, popup-blocker settings, or reinstall your browser.

A different browser on your PC may work correctly with `www.google.com`.

Comment: yes, i am able to access google.co.in from my browser. but the same problem persists!

Comment: how do you mean, the same problem persists? when accessing www.google.co.in what does the page source contain?

Comment: i am terribly sorry that when posting the question the page source that i had provided was indeed of a search result obtained from google.co.in. i have corrected that now. so, when i search using google.co.in the behavior is similar as stated in the question. makes no difference.

Comment: there is no difference apart from the fact that the page source will contain google.co.in instead of google.com

Answer (score -3):

Ask your network admin about your problem. It will work best.

Comment: Say if you do not have a Network Admin? Or you are the Network Admin? Your answer does not help at all.